# Data balancing in image classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image-processing, data-preprocessing, timeseries-segmentation

I've to segment defects from an image. The image consists of only tomatoes with it's defects in it. The defects and tomatoes in the dataset are as follows:

```
tomato = 20900
```

Defects:

```
tip = 2129
spots holes = 804
cuts cracks = 267
shrivelled = 193
glare = 3485
back tip = 137
stalk = 119
green area = 610
```

As one can see the data is highly unbalanced. Within a single image of tomatoes we may find some defects and we may not find any. How to do training of such cases of multi-class identification and classification ?
I've tried many standard models in given in tensorflow-object-detection api.It detects `tomatoes` and `glare` well as there numbers are higher. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling will not solve a non-problem: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352) A good start would be to build separate probabilistic models for each separate type of defect. These can serve as benchmarks for a more complex "omnibus" model that outputs probabilities for all defects simultaneously (and accounts for the fact that the defects likely occur together sometimes).

Comment: Is this a classification or a segmentation problem?

Comment: @0asa I've to both segment and then classify.